# Table 'tblCustomer' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Occurs when I try to set the identity_insert to ON in the SQL DATAMANAGEMENT STUDIO.

The worst is I do not know why should I deal with this value, and I am not even sure that the following code hits more than the copy of the database in the local memory.

I have got this message previously, when the debug hits the SaveChanges line : 
"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tblCustomer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

```
    ` public ActionResult Submit( 
    Customer obj) //validation runs 
    { 

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CustomerDal Dal = new CustomerDal();
            Dal.Customer.Add(obj);     //in memory
            Dal.SaveChanges();          //physical commit 

            return View("Customer", obj);
        }
        else
        { 
            return View("EnterCustomer", obj);
        }
    }`

    public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.none)]
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{7,7}$")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

    public class CustomerDal : DbContext 
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("tblCustomer");
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

}
```

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCustomer](`
 `[CustomerCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,`
 `[CustomerName] [varchar](50) NULL,`
 `CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCustomer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED`
 `(`
 `[CustomerCode] ASC`
 `)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,`
 `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)`
 `ON [PRIMARY]`
 `) ON [PRIMARY]`

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <i>Customer Name : </i> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName)

    <br>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerName)
    <br>

        <i>Customer Code : </i> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerCode)

            <br>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerCode)
            <br>
            <input id = "Submit1" type = "submit" value = "submit"/>

            }
```

Comment: Very strange indeed. Nothing points that you have an identity column, and still you have that error... Can you show the code to create the obj Customer object?

Comment: I added the html code that initiates the Submit action (fill the customer object)

Comment: The error clearly comes from nested object related to `obj`. This can't be answered without seeing the entire object graph that's added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table *tblCustomer* has an identity column, and assuming that you are configuring mappings using notations, specify the *DatabaseGenerated* for the identity property:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

If you do not have identity column on yout table, set it to *None*.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx

Can you provide more details about your table and EF mapping?

Comment: I do not mention identity colum either in my C# code and my SQL table property. But the error forces me to deal with this problem.

Comment: @Breece, I edited to post to inform that If you do not have identity column on yout table, set DatabaseGenerated to *None*. Can you provide more details about your table and EF mapping?

Comment: Thank you. But the problem persists.
The customercode is a string.